# Error:No such property: targetPlatform for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.NdkConfig

Tags: android, gradle, ffmpeg, android-ndk, abi

I am trying to build `FFMPEG` into my `JNI` code with gradle in Android Studio. I have build FFMPEG as a `.so` file, in order to adapt different platform, I build it for different `ABI(arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, mip, etc)`.Then I need to determine the ABI  of the current build in the build.gradle file.

Refer [Experimental Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-ABI-Specific-Configurations), my build.gradle look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.native'    
model{
    repositories {
        prebuilt(PrebuiltLibraries){
            ffmpeg{
                headers.srcDir "src/main/jni/build/${targetPlatform.getName()}/include"
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/jni/build/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libvflibrary.so")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 24
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 24
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }

        ndk{
            //platformVersion = 21
            moduleName = "library-jni"
            stl = 'gnustl_static'
            toolchain = "clang"
            abiFilters.addAll(['armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips'])
            cppFlags.addAll(['-std=c++11', '-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS'])
            ldLibs.addAll(['log', 'android', 'z', 'EGL', 'GLESv2'])
        }

        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    source{
                        srcDirs 'src/main/jni'
                    }
                    dependencies {
                        library 'ffmpeg' linkage 'shared'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error:

> Error:No such property: targetPlatform for class:
>   com.android.build.gradle.managed.NdkConfig.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can solve this, please?

Comment: make sure you use `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha1"` or higher

Comment: I am use classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0", still get that error.